# OCAPI request length restriction

Tags: rest-api, api, commerce-cloud

if I send a PATCH request for a customer resource (.../customers/xyz) with the following data:

```
{"birthday":"11.11.1980","email":"max@mustermann.de","first_name":"Max","last_name":"Mustermann","title":"Prof. Dr."}
```

I get the response:

```
{"_v":"18.8","fault":{"arguments":{"body":"{\"birthday\":\"11.11.1980\",\"email\":\"max@mustermann.de\",\"first_name\":\"Max\",\"last_name\":\"Mustermann\",\"ti"},"type":"BodyDecodingException","message":"An error occurred while decoding the request, the body was '{\"birthday\":\"11.11.1980\",\"email\":\"max@mustermann.de\",\"first_name\":\"Max\",\"last_name\":\"Mustermann\",\"ti'."}}
```

The body of my request seems to be truncated by OCAPI before parsing.Is there any length restriction for the OCAPI calls?

Comment: What is the content type of request being sent?

Comment: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Comment: Ok, I did found the solution. The problem was the wrong date format. The date has to be formatted this way: yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: please post it as an answer!